# @Transactional transactionManager not working problem

Tags: spring-boot, transactions

I tried to update entity using `@Transactional` annotation, but not working. I tried to update nick in `UserEntity` and I checked new nick I send in URL was applied in service layer. I expected after method `updateProfile` in `UserService` end, `TransactionManager` Open and make new ProxyObject and update DB but it doesn't work. Here is my situation, this is my `UserApiController`:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class UserApiController{

@EmailAuth
@PostMapping("/email-auth-completion/{code}")
public ResponseEntity verifyEmail(@PathVariable("code") String code) {
    log.info("[실행] UserApiController.verifyEmail");
    Map<Object, Object> data = redisUtil.getEmailCertification(code);

    log.info("[정보] " + redisUtil.getEmailCertification(code).toString());
    userService.updateEmailAuth(data);
    return ResponseFormat.RESPONSE_OK;
}
}
```

File `UserService.java`

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService {


@Transactional
    public void updateProfile(ProfileUpdateReqDto reqDto, Long id) {
        log.info("[실행] updateProfile" + id);
        log.info("[정보] 트랜젝션 포함 여부 : " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        log.info("[정보] reqDto.getNick() : " + reqDto.getNick());
        User user = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByid(id)).orElseThrow(
                () -> new CustomException(ErrorCode.NOTFOUND_USER))
                .get();

        log.info("[정보] user : " + user.toString());

        if (checkNickDuplication(reqDto.getNick())) {
            throw new CustomException(PARAM_NICK, ErrorCode.DUPLICATE_USER_NICK);
        }

        log.info("[정보] 트랜젝션 포함 여부 : " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        user.updateProfile(
                reqDto.getProfileImage(),
                reqDto.getNick()
        );
    }
}
```

Looking log:
"TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()" is false and there is no "transactionManager" begin in log. so I think transactionManager is not working. what should I do?

Actually, it was working before but it is not working suddenly. I tried to follow the rules for using annotations `@Transactional`, but it didn't work. My working set is SpringBoot 3.1.1 , Java 17.